# AJAX posting to CakePHP controller action

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am posting some form values used for registration into a cakePHP controller action. The code is like this

```
var params='firstname='+encodeURIComponent(firstname) +'&lastname='+encodeURIComponent(lastname)+'&emailid='+encodeURIComponent(emailid)+'&password='+encodeURIComponent(password);

xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

this is doing the posting and I can see it in the Firebug in the POST section source as

```
firstname=name&lastname=name&emailid=mymailid&password=123123
```

But when I print $this->data in the action , it is not not showing any values. I have even used $_POST and it is also returning anything..

What I done wrong here..?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a request header that is required when using POST to send variables:

try this instead:

```
var params='firstname='+encodeURIComponent(firstname) +'&lastname='+encodeURIComponent(lastname)+'&emailid='+encodeURIComponent(emailid)+'&password='+encodeURIComponent(password);

xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: I have added it and used $this->params['url']; and $this->request['url'];.The first one is only showing the URL that I am posting to and second one showing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try in controller like following:

```
$this->params['url']; // this will give an array of parameters
```

Or, `$this->request['url'];  // this will give an array of parameters`